# Unable to put text more than one char for certain HTML input from Selenium Java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, sendkeys

In **certain** pages of an UI app, Selenium Java is unable to put text with more than one char into a HTML input text bar (
`<input type="text" id="Name " value="" maxlength="32" tabindex="10">`).
I tried ways below, and 'data' in sample code is the text "abcd" and only the first 'a' can be placed. I need help on this special Selenium problem only for certain pages (not for similar majority pages).

1. Normal way:

```
ele.clear();
ele.sendKeys(data);
```

2. Add Enter:

```
ele.clear();
ele.sendKeys(data);
Utils.sleep(200);
ele.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

3. Java Script way:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('" + elementId + "').setAttribute('value', '" + data + "')");
```

4. Loop char by char:

```
ele.clear();
for (int j = 0; j < data.length(); j++){
    char c = data.charAt(j);
    String s = new StringBuilder().append(c).toString();
    ele.sendKeys(s);
    Utils.sleep(100);
}
```

Comment: when you try manually were you able to enter more than one character?

Comment: Yes.
Many manual working actions cannot be done by Selenium.

Comment: 1. What browser you are using? 2. While debugging, were you able to see the `abcd` value at step `ele.sendKeys(data);`? 3. Have you tried by changing xPath?

Comment: Answer Nandan's questions:
1. Chrome (FireFox is same). 2. Yes. I see data="abcd" right before running it, and see HTML <input ... value="a"> right after. 4. Yes. Tried to get ele by both ID and XPath, and I feel this irrelevant.
Thank you to pay attention on my question!